# What's the meaning of "through" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a comment made by a poster on an [article](http://www.salon.com/2011/10/26/why_i_refuse_to_text_message/) about *texting*:

> I love technology. However, I will not get a cell phone nor will I text. My phone is **through** the internet. As has happened several times, I have to pay attention when I walk down the street or people who are texting or talking on their cell phones would run into me. That they don't even comprehend this is another reason.

What does it mean when he said his phone is "through" the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He means that the medium through which he makes and receives telephone calls is the internet.

Use of *be* instead of a more active verb to express the medium or source of a service is not unusual colloquially.

> My TV is through cable.
>   My news is from NPR.
>   His suits are all from a bespoke tailor.